# Get RAW header of http response

Tags: http, go, response

How to get raw header of response as string like this:

```
alt-svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="44,43,39,35"
cache-control: private, max-age=0
content-encoding: br
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
date: Tue, 08 Jan 2019 06:19:47 GMT
expires: -1
server: gws
set-cookie: 1P_JAR=2019-01-08-06; expires=Thu, 07-Feb-2019 06:19:47 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com
set-cookie: SIDCC=ABtHo-HHNcja-cEEFEUXtBmLOdql4RTVMCWKGApEFFb8lWSAqaTF_fi0gDLoWaCzH3ogvEofah0; expires=Mon, 08-Apr-2019 06:19:47 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; priority=high
status: 200
```

Because I want get the multiple `set-cookie` value from the response header.
Use `Http.Response.Header.Get("set-cookies")` just return the last row.

Or how can I get the multiple cookies?

Comment: Have you tried using [`Values("set-cookie")`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Header.Values) instead of [`Get("set-cookie")`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Header.Get)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the *raw* headers, you'll need to write some wrapper for [`net.Conn`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Conn) which captures the raw header before it is interpreted by the `http` library.

But you don't really seem to need the raw header--or even the full header at all. If your goal is simply to read multiple cookies, the easiest way to do this is with the [`Cookies`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Response.Cookies) method on the response.

An intermediate option between these two is to read the entire [`Header`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Response) field of the response. This will present the *full* header, but its order is not guaranteed, and minimal parsing will have been done (to remove newlines, etc), so it can't be said this is truly "raw". It does, however, preserve multiple values, in case of duplicate headers, by storing all header values in a `[]string`. So for the purposes of this question, this should be perfectly adequate (although `Response.Cookies`, as mentioned above, would be easier).

Comment: thanks. Resolved.  Response.header is an map header key: value. So, `cookies := resp.Header["Set-Cookie"]` got an array of all cookies

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, the best option for roundtripping a response is
`httputil#DumpResponse`:

```
package raw

import (
   "bufio"
   "bytes"
   "net/http"
   "net/http/httputil"
)

func encode(res *http.Response) ([]byte, error) {
   return httputil.DumpResponse(res, false)
}

func decode(data []byte) (*http.Response, error) {
   return http.ReadResponse(bufio.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(data)), nil)
}
```

Or, if you just want the cookies, you can do this:

```
package raw

import (
   "encoding/json"
   "net/http"
)

func encode(res *http.Response) ([]byte, error) {
   return json.Marshal(res.Cookies())
}

func decode(data []byte) ([]http.Cookie, error) {
   var c []http.Cookie
   if e := json.Unmarshal(data, &c); e != nil {
      return nil, e
   }
   return c, nil
}
```

Or for a single cookie:

```
package raw

import (
   "encoding/json"
   "net/http"
)

func encode(res *http.Response, name string) ([]byte, error) {
   for _, c := range res.Cookies() {
      if c.Name == name {
         return json.Marshal(c)
      }
   }
   return nil, http.ErrNoCookie
}

func decode(data []byte) (*http.Cookie, error) {
   c := new(http.Cookie)
   if e := json.Unmarshal(data, c); e != nil {
      return nil, e
   }
   return c, nil
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil#DumpResponse

Comment: Note that [httputil's DumpResponse](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http/httputil#DumpRequest) still parses the response into a canonical form, meaning the order of headers, and capitalization of the first letter, may not match what was received on the wire. This means you may not actually get a bit-for-bit "raw" representation. See [CanonicalHeaderKey](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#CanonicalHeaderKey) for what occurs during canonicalization.

Answer (score 1):

The standard http lib parsed the header by default.
Using fasthttp (you will need to re-write your router and handler function) will give you ability to get the raw header.

- https://github.com/valyala/fasthttp#switching-from-nethttp-to-fasthttp
- https://godoc.org/github.com/valyala/fasthttp#RequestHeader.RawHeaders

Answer (score -3):

use `fmt.Printf("%+v", resp.Header)`

can write all header to a string like below:

```
map[Set-Cookie:[CASPRIVACY=""; Path=/ CASTGC=TGT-1248283-0BRja0uNQR9PntBl4HnrzKA44q5XDQXxA5FRVcnO9Xn6CkTU6S-passport; Path=/ CASLOGC=%7B%22myuniRole%22%3A0%2C%22username%22%3A%22a6051b9d08384f3ea2d203e744d3f7e6%22%2C%22mycuRole%22%3A0%2C%22userId%22%3A192676671%2C%22myinstRole%22%3A0%2C%22realName%22%3A%22%E9%9B%B7%E7%BA%A2%E6%A2%85%22%2C%22uuid%22%3A%22V4eoYpNB%22%2C%22headPic%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fimage.xxx.com%2Fzhs%2Fapp%2Fcontent%2F201812%2Ff0b20d740df04d3196a20bc39f58ab56_s3.png%22%7D; Domain=.xxxx.com; Path=/ SERVERID=958b97eacbe3c49360ace2dfc0bd31b4|1546915535|1546915533;Path=/] Pragma:[no-cache] Expires:[Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT] Cache-Control:[no-cache no-store] Location:[http://online.xxx.com/onlineSchool/?ticket=ST-3285248-UiTbNt7bnUwXdtWSznIT-passport.xxxx.com] Date:[Tue, 08 Jan 2019 02:45:35 GMT] Content-Length:[0] Connection:[keep-alive]]
```

Is hardly to get all cookies from the string by use split and regx

Comment: This neither accesses "raw" headers, nor does it allow access to multiple cookies. This simply dumps a sub-optimal representation of the (non-raw) response header. Hardly an answer to the question in any case.